# Module to be imported not being found Javascript

Tags: javascript, import

I hope someone can help me as this is driving me nuts! I have had a good look via Google and found nothing to explicitly help me.

I am trying out this audio repo (quite old): https://github.com/cutterbl/SoundTouchJS

I am running the example given and finding difficulty with the import that occurs in line 7.

```js
// This is pulling SoundTouchJS from the local file system. See the README for proper usage.
import { PitchShifter } from 'soundtouch.js';
```

I've read the READEME but I find the instructions there ambiguous.

My file structure is this,

[image: screenshot of my project structure]

and I have tried many options for the path to 'soundtouch.js' but all fail with a message of : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

I am not using the Node server side of this, but running it from MAMP instead, is that part of the problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Andy

Comment: Which file are you importing the module into? If it's example.js, as in the image, you need to move up to SoundTouchJS directory, then into dist, then soundtouch.js. '../dist/soundtouch.js'

Comment: HI ..thank you for getting back to me so quickly. Yes, example.js is called in index.html   I tried that idea of changing the path as you suggest, myself and I just tested it again and I'm still getting      
  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).  

The console is also saying "an error occurred trying to load the resource" .
Is that. clue ?